# Can't get Resharper 6.0 to work with xUnit.net

Tags: xunit, resharper-6.0

I have downloaded the xunit contrib for resharper but I can't get it to work. The installation instructions do not work. Does anyone else having same problem?

When I try to run the unit tests I get an error "No test found".

Comment: Where do the installation instructions go wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My problem was solved. I had those files blocked in the zip somehow. I had to unblock each file individually and it worked.

Comment: That was my exact problem. I had to open properties for each file and click the "unblock" button. Notice that this must be done to the originally downloaded files in your C:\Users\(user-name) folder. If you try to do this to the files installed in the resharper folders it will appear that clicking the button works, but it has no effect.

Comment: to be clear unzip the files to an unprotected folder before unblocking, e.g. your desktop, then unblock them one at a time then move to /program files/...

Comment: Alternatively, you can right click on the zip file itself and click properties 'unblock'. That way you don't have to do each file one by one

Answer (score 0):

You have to install this http://xunitcontrib.codeplex.com/releases/view/67893.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Problem. The above solution didn't work for me. What did work for me was to right click the "Solution Folder" select properties>Security and add myself into  the list of users with full permissions.